# more efficient way of writing functions for buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jquery so please excuse me if this question seems silly... I have a website with 20 buttons which have similar but not exact functions. I have been planning on writing separate functions for each button but was wondering if there was an easier, more efficient way of doing this. here are 2 of my buttons:

```
$('#architect').hover (function() { 
  $('.blank').addClass('txtarchitect');  
  $('.bates,.han').addClass('over');  
  }, 
  function(){ 
  $('.blank').removeClass('txtarchitect');  
  $('.bates,.han').removeClass('over');  
  } 
); 
});

$('#educator').hover (function() { 
  $('.blank').addClass('txteducator');  
  $('.lee,.gorman').addClass('over'); 
  }, 
  function(){ 
  $('.blank').removeClass('txteducator');  
  $('.lee,.gorman').removeClass('over');  
  } 
); 
});
```

any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you even need any JavaScript at all for this?  Can't you accomplish what you want with just the CSS `:hover` selector?

Comment: @gilly3 How is CSS going to add a class to element B when you hover over element A?

Comment: @Juan - If element B or an ancestor of element B is a sibling of element A, then you wouldn't need to change the class of element B - just change its style using the sibling combinators.  If element B is higher up the document hierarchy than element A, then JavaScript is required.

Comment: @gilly3 But you're making lots of assumptions about the HTML structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple function that parameterizes the values that change should do the job

```
function addHoverHandler( buttonId, blankCls, overClasses) {
   $('#'+ buttonId).hover(
     function(){
       $('.blank').addClass(blankCls);  
       $(overClasses).addClass('over');  
     },
     function (){
       $('.blank').removeClass(blankCls);  
       $(overClasses).removeClass('over');   
     }
   );
}

var buttons = [
   {btnId: 'educator', blankCls: 'texteducator', overClasses: '.lee,.gorman'},
   {btnId: 'architect', blankCls: 'textatchitect', overClasses: '.bates,.han'}
];



for (var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   var btn = buttons[i];
   addHoverHandler(btn.btnId, btn.blankCls, btn.overClasses);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. That said, I think the OP would be better served by rethinking his approach; the whole *"My God, it's full of buttons"* approach promises to be a logistical and usability nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, but SO is for answering questions of how to do something, which I did. I'm not going to claim that there is a better way to do something that I have no information as to how it's used. But yeah, as I wrote, I thought, really, 20 buttons on the page?

Comment: @juan - thanks so much for your answer, will try it straight away! i agree there are too many buttons but i am only the programmer on this project and have no control over the design. appreciate everyone's input!

Answer (score 1):

```
function button(class1, class2, class3, dir){
    if(dir == 1){
        $(this).addClass(class1);
        $("."+class2+", ."+class3).addClass("over");
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass(class1);
        $("."+class2+", ."+class3).removeClass("over");
    }
}
```

then:

```
$("#educator").hover(function(){
    button("txteducator", "bates", "han", 1);
}, function(){
    button("txteducator", "bates", "han", 0);
});
```

Do the same for each button. If the `class1` variable will always be "txt" plus the id of the element being hovered, then instead of providing it you can change the `class1` lines in the `button()` function to versions of this:

```
$(this).addClass("txt"+$(this).id());
```

Comment: This is in the right direction, but you're still going to have to call hover 20 times, it can easily be more abstracted, see my answer. Also, the names of your class1,class2,class3 are pretty bad, since they imply they do the same thing.

Comment: `class1, class2, class3` are obviously placeholders. Since I don't know what those classes *do* in OP's code...